Does Superset work with QuestDB 8.0.0 or higher?
I recently upgraded from QuestDB 7.4.2 to QuestDB 8.1.2. I use Apache Superset 4.0.0 for visualisation, and this worked fine before the upgrade, but now the questdb-connect library is throwing an unhelpful error:
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521208472Z ERROR:flask_appbuilder.api:'NoneType' object is not callable
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521233355Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521237176Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/api/__init__.py", line 110, in wraps
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521240585Z     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521242959Z   File "/app/superset/views/base_api.py", line 127, in wraps
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521245388Z     raise ex
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521248040Z   File "/app/superset/views/base_api.py", line 121, in wraps
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521250464Z     duration, response = time_function(f, self, *args, **kwargs)
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521253488Z   File "/app/superset/utils/core.py", line 1463, in time_function
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521255789Z     response = func(*args, **kwargs)
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521258381Z   File "/app/superset/utils/log.py", line 255, in wrapper
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521261480Z     value = f(*args, **kwargs)
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521263836Z   File "/app/superset/databases/api.py", line 742, in table_metadata
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521266910Z     table_info = get_table_metadata(database, table_name, schema_name)
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521269293Z   File "/app/superset/databases/utils.py", line 67, in get_table_metadata
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521271766Z     columns = database.get_columns(table_name, schema_name)
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521274575Z   File "/app/superset/models/core.py", line 839, in get_columns
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521277035Z     return self.db_engine_spec.get_columns(
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521279705Z   File "/app/superset/db_engine_specs/base.py", line 1340, in get_columns
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521282333Z     cast(list[SQLAColumnType], inspector.get_columns(table_name, schema))
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521284920Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/questdb_connect/inspector.py", line 79, in get_columns
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521287336Z     return self.format_table_columns(table_name, result_set)
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521289845Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/questdb_connect/inspector.py", line 87, in format_table_columns
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521292427Z     return [
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521294748Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/questdb_connect/inspector.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521297122Z     "type": resolve_type_from_name(row[1])(),
2024-10-28T13:28:21.521299536Z TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

I'm not sure what's wrong, has support for Superset been discontinued? Why won't my code work any more?

This was a problem in questdb-connect version 1.1.2 and older versions. questdb-connect 1.1.3 now supports the VARCHAR type, so workarounds are no longer needed.

In QuestDB 8.0.0 and later versions, there is a UTF-8 Encoded VARCHAR type available. Its recommended to use this over STRING where possible, as it usually takes less space to store, and improves query performance.
However, the questdb-connect library does not support this type yet, only STRING. Therefore, if you try to connect to a table and retrieve data from a VARCHAR column, the connector might break.
Most likely, you swapped some STRING columns to VARCHAR and are now experiencing this incompatibility.
To resolve this, you could:

Swap to STRING type where necessary, for compatibility reasons.
Ensure that the queries you send to the database cast any VARCHAR columns or values into STRING.

For option 1, you can use the following SQL:
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE STRING;

For option 2, simply use cast syntax
SELECT v::STRING, cast(v as STRING)

Hopefully questdb-connect will be updated soon to work with the VARCHAR type as expected.

Update: questdb-connect 1.1.3 adds support for VARCHAR.
